# App broken after meteor update, can't determine what package update broke it

Tags: meteor

Here's what I know:

- After running meteor update my meteor app is broken. When I run meteor on the CLI, I get the error below, at the bottom of this post.
- I was already using Meteor 1.5, and that was NOT upgraded by the meteor update.

Here's what I DON'T know:

- What package update caused this error?

Here's what I have tried:

- Deleted versions file, ran meteor update. Still got same error.
- Updated to Meteor 1.5.1. Got different errors (sorry, did not log them :( )
- Deleted and reinstalled Meteor from scratch. Still got same error.
- Deleted local copy of the app source and cloned again from git. Also uninstalled and reinstalled Meteor again before doing this. Still got same error.
- Tried: meteor update modules (after which I got the message that modules was already at the latest version).

I'm not sure how to isolate what package update caused this problem, as I do not have a log of what was updated (a mistake I won't be making again!). And I have the package versions file in my gitignore (basically per best practices), so I can't look at git history to see what packages were updated and might be causing the problem.

The error:

```
W20170713-10:43:06.627(-5)? (STDERR) /Users/[redacted]/Source/[redacted]/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:391 
W20170713-10:43:06.654(-5)? (STDERR) }).run(); 
W20170713-10:43:06.655(-5)? (STDERR) ^ 
W20170713-10:43:06.656(-5)? (STDERR) 
W20170713-10:43:06.656(-5)? (STDERR) TypeError: module.makeNsSetter is not a function 
W20170713-10:43:06.657(-5)? (STDERR) at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.shell-server.main.js (packages/shell-server/main.js:1:55) 
W20170713-10:43:06.657(-5)? (STDERR) at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:333:9) 
W20170713-10:43:06.657(-5)? (STDERR) at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:228:16) 
W20170713-10:43:06.658(-5)? (STDERR) at /Users/[redacted]/Source/[redacted]/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/shell-server.js:568:15 
W20170713-10:43:06.658(-5)? (STDERR) at /Users/[redacted]/Source/[redacted]/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/shell-server.js:574:3 
W20170713-10:43:06.658(-5)? (STDERR) at /Users/[redacted]/Source/[redacted]/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:338:34 
W20170713-10:43:06.658(-5)? (STDERR) at Array.forEach (native) 
W20170713-10:43:06.659(-5)? (STDERR) at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/[redacted]/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.0.edxpxb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11) 
W20170713-10:43:06.659(-5)? (STDERR) at /Users/[redacted]/Source/[redacted]/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:158:5 
W20170713-10:43:06.660(-5)? (STDERR) at /Users/[redacted]/Source/[redacted]/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:387:5
```

Comment: Try to remove the entire meteor installation and global .meteor -folder from your computer and then reinstall.

Comment: Just a guess, but the errors seems to be related to some core functionalities. I had a similar issue after updating to 1.5 and it got resolved, when I installed babel-runtime via `meteor npm install --save babel-runtime`

Comment: @iiro That's what I meant by uninstalling and reinstalling meteor.

Comment: @Jankapunkt Thanks for the suggestion. I gave that a try but still get the same error message.

Comment: @Jankapunkt your method worked for me. thx.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved my problem via the scorched earth method, basically just creating a new meteor project and copying over my app source alone and then installing all the packages listed in the original project and packages files. I don't know what my original problem was, but everything is working now.